# Two querry with the same value

Tags: update

I made this querry that counts all the statuses "1" for a certain ID and their summarizes add in the column "result" and it works great:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('COUNT(*)');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__climbing'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('#__climbing.status')." = ".$db->quote(1)." AND ".$db->quoteName('#__climbing.link_id')." = " .$db->quote($link_id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$score = $db->loadResult();
$result = "UPDATE #__mt_links SET result =". $score." WHERE link_id=".$link_id ;
$db->setQuery( $result );
$db->query();
```

Now I want to add the same result into another column. I added another querry, but it does not work and still executing only one:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('COUNT(*)');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__climbing'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('#__climbing.status')." = ".$db->quote(1)." AND ".$db->quoteName('#__climbing.link_id')." = " .$db->quote($link_id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$score = $db->loadResult();
$result = "UPDATE #__mt_links SET price =". $score." WHERE link_id=".$link_id ;
$result2 = "UPDATE #__hikers SET score =". $score." WHERE link_id=".$link_id ;
$db->setQuery( $result );
$db->setQuery( $result2 );
$db->query();
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$result = "UPDATE #__mt_links SET price =". $score." WHERE link_id=".$link_id ;
$result2 = "UPDATE #__hikers SET score =". $score." WHERE link_id=".$link_id ;
$db->setQuery( $result );
$db->execute();
$db->setQuery( $result2 );
$db->execute();
```

Comment: (Remember to mark it as the correct answer otherwise the site will bump it as an unanswered question on occasion)

Comment: Note that you should replace `$db->query();` with `$db->execute();`

Comment: Good catch, Lodder.